# MouseEventArgs.GetPosition(...) Not Returning Relative Position in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I have two event handlers in an application that provide a 'Drag' type operation (not an actual Drag Event). For this, I have event handlers to handle the **MouseDown** and **MouseMove** events.

```
    private void OnMouseDown(object sender,MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //The following CORRECTLY gives the relative position
        //Note the MouseButtonEventArgs type
        Point position = e.GetPosition(this.myCanvas);
        Point relativePosition = e.GetPosition(this.myUsercontrol);

        //Do something with position and relative position
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender,MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //The following INCORRECTLY gives the relative position.
        //Note the MouseEventArgs type

        Point position = e.GetPosition(this.myCanvas);
        Point relativePosition = e.GetPosition(this.myUsercontrol);

        //Do something with position and relative position
    }
```

The problem I am having is I need to utilize the relative position of the mouse during the **MouseMove** event. However, it is returning (0,0) when I call GetPosition(...) on MouseEventArgs, but is working perfectly fine when invoked on MouseButtonEventArgs. Why wou

Comment: Some XAML? to check the relation of Canvas and UserControl.

Comment: The UserControl has a StackPanel which has the Canvas as a child. It is constructed programatically (I know this is bad :) ).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Mouse events is that they don't exactly only happen in the context you are looking at, the same event happens everywhere. And if some other element sets MouseEventArgs.Handled = true... well weird things start happening. I was getting the same problem, e.GetPosition() was returning a constant {-25;-170}, but only when the window was in normal mode, when maximized everything worked just fine. The culprit was window level event handler setting e.Handled = true;
So check where else your application is using mouse events